# What kind of wall/ceiling texture is this?

Tags: drywall, design, texture

Can you please help me identify this wall/ceiling texture and how to achieve it? I recently had to replace a patch and cannot figure out how to duplicate the pattern.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know what to do next.

Comment: Looks like they dry stomped the paint... can you post a picture with a wider field of view, so we can identify regular patterns across the surface? If you can, lay on your back on the floor to take the picture with a light source from one side of the room, to give some contrast (soft shadows). Ambient light from a window should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an actual name for this, maybe grade school art.

After doing all your patching and smoothing out the wall, get a 1" knife, putty knife, dip it in some drywall mud and dap it on the wall. Do it a couple of times without redipping to get the thinner, smaller lines. Dap and twist a bit to get the uneven lines. After it partially dries, you can flatten out a few with the knife to get the smashed down look. Experiment a bit and you'll be surprised how close you can match it. You're lucky, this is an easier pattern to match than most.

Comment: @Stefan Since you've probably got some drywall left over from your patching, you could practice on that extra drywall until you're reasonably comfortable, then do it for real on the ceiling. Also, I'm sure you've thought of this, but in case you haven't, this will be that opportunity to give the whole ceiling that new coat of paint you've been wanting to apply! ;) (i.e. it'll be hard to match the existing color, may as well do the whole thing)